# Sharepoint-hosted app with workflow deployment failed

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, workflow-manager

I tried creating a Sharepoint-hosted app with workflow using Sharepoint 2013 and Visual studio 2015 CE(also tried VS 2013 CE) as in this [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt148590.aspx). When I tried to deploy, it failed with the following error message

Error Message.

> @"Error 1
>           CorrelationId: 15bc3687-1651-4998-a950-62604875a927
>           ErrorDetail: There was an error during the operation.
>           ErrorType: Configuration
>           ErrorTypeName: Configuration
>           ExceptionMessage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>           Source: Common
>           SourceName: Common App Deployment Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': Failed to install SharePoint Add-in. 
>   Please see the output window for details.

I also tried creating a very simple workflow by just terminating the workflow. Again the same problem.

If I publish the app(*.app) package, am unable to add it to the team site. All it says is
      `Sorry, This app is not supported on your server`
[image: ScreenShot]

I tried following workarounds for this as pointed by some blogs,

1. Changing the AppPreRequisite Id to '**B1DDD88F-6ADD-4700-B5CD-18E451635E24**' in Appmanifest.xml file.    *** - [Not working. Same problem]***.
2. Deleting the AppPreRequisite section in Appmanifest.xml file.
     On deleting this section it stopped saying unsupported app message and I can able to click on `ADD IT` button. But the app gets failed to add in the site.
3. Updated Workflow manager to CU2. **-[Same problem]**

   **Extra Information :** 
   Workflow manager is working fine because if I add workflow to a webpart using Sharepoint designer it works fine.

This is killing me for more than 3 weeks.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.